# Deleting a folder and re-adding it back later via a rename

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have 2 projects commited to my SVN repository 'myproject' and 'myproject-2'. Both are under the same directory.

If I delete 'myproject' and commit these changes.

Then later if I rename 'myproject-2' to 'myproject'. Will I hit any issues here? 
i.e. are there going to be any conflicts after the rename?

Im using TortoiseSVN to do the delete and rename.

Comment: The only issue is that you should now be a bit careful when working with peg- and operational- revisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've stated it there, you shouldn't run into any issues.

Where you might hit issues is if you try to roll back the first commit (the delete), but other than that you should be fine.